# How to extract information through script from Global Builds Stats Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am having a requirement to send weekly mail with details about the jobs ran on the jenkins. I have managed to install the plugin and can see the graph as well.

[image]

Can someone guide me on the script part, how to extract the data and send in mail. Also, if data can be sent in graphical form that will be best.

Using below command I can see the chart in browser directly.

```
<jenkins/hudson_url>/plugin/global-build-stats/showChart?buildStatId=<Chart id>
```

However, when I am trying the below curl command to download the image, I am not getting it.

```
curl -O <jenkins/hudson_url>/plugin/global-build-stats/showChart?buildStatId=<Chart id>
```

Getting below two files, which is not image or relevant data.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root    root         62 Nov 14 07:04 osw.hb
-rw-------. 1 root    root        969 Nov 14 07:04 showChart?buildStatId=<chart id>
```

Content of "showchartfile" is below.

```
Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
```

Which looks like an authentication issue. Ideally, it should not come as I am using chart id. Below is the link of documention of the API.

```
https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=46336030
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. The chart id works only for existing user. Which means username and passwd need to be provided with curl command. Have used below one. Its working now.

```
curl -u Username:Passwd -O <jenkins/hudson_url>/plugin/global-build-stats/showChart?buildStatId=<Chart id>
```